# Status bar Hidden Issue, when present QLPreview controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, statusbar, qlpreviewcontroller

Following is my code:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];

previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.dataSource = self;
[self presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I have set **ViewController** based status bar property to NO.

When I present **QLPreviewController**, the status bar is hidden.
Kindly tell me the solution of this problem.

Comment: your status bar color is light content..???

Comment: yes status bar is light content throughout application

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.dataSource = self;
[self presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:^{ [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if below properties are set like this in your applications info.plist file.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
```

Comment: You have mentioned that status bar hidden issue. You want to show it or hide it?

Comment: i want status bar is always shown the problem is that when i present QLPreview controller for displaying image at that time the status bar is hide and when this controller is dismiss then the statusbar is automatically shown...

Comment: If you have set properties UIStatusBarHidden  UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance like above then status bar will be hidden always.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using view controller-based status bar control (which makes sense for apps that are compatible with iOS6 and earlier), you can take control of whether a status bar is shown by adding a line to your presented view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method.
To show the status bar, add

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
```

Comment: As long as UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance in the app's plist is set to false, this code line will make the status bar show. Put it in the `viewWillAppear:` method of `QLPreviewController`.

Comment: but how can i access the QLPreviewController's viewWillAppear method its built in Controller of Quick Look Framework

Comment: You can make a simple subclass (Apple's documentation doesn't indicate that you can't), or you can use @Mayank's code, which is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, if your view controller class is actually a navigation controller you will need to override the `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` method of the view controller it is showing.